# Adding 3rd party libraries to Android.Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

How can I add Android 3rd party libraries to Xamarin project using Xamarin Studio?

EDIT

I want to add [this](https://github.com/antonyt/InfiniteViewPager) from GitHub. In android studio I would add dependency to Gradle like this:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.antonyt.infiniteviewpager:library:1.0.0'
}
```

but what is the solution in case of Xamarin if I don't have .jar?

I tried to follow [this guide](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding-a-java-library/) to Bind a Java Library but without success.

Comment: Check this out: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-jar/

Comment: Thanks Luca, but actually this is a guide I linked in my question.

Comment: Download the butterknife .jar and follow my link

Answer (score 0):

xamarin dont have buttterKnife libralry but you can check [this](https://components.xamarin.com/view/cheeseknife)  component is like butterknife library and check [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/components_walkthrough/) on how to instal components in xamarin

Comment: Sorry Kastriot, I should specify my question. ButterKnife was just an example.

Comment: ok so i the second link you have xamarin components and how to add them on project

Answer (score 0):

As Kastriot mentioned earlier, you can try other libraries such as:

CheeseKnife - https://components.xamarin.com/view/cheeseknife

Genetics - https://components.xamarin.com/view/genetics

These should both be available on NuGet as well.

If you want the original library, you can create a Xamarin Android Binding Project

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding-a-java-library/

Or you can work on a Java -> C# port of the original library like the ones above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jon. Do you know if I can bind project but without .jar, or I need to create .jar from git repository first and then bind it? Sorry if that doesn't make sense but I'm complete newbie in Xamarin:)

Comment: You will need to get the respective .jar or .aar from either a download/release or build it yourself in a respective Android IDE. Luckily it can be found directly here:

http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife#download

However you should be careful to understand the differences between Java and C# as Java uses Annotations and C# uses Attributes. It makes me think that these two libraries were created for that reason(Closer to home with C#). (Looks like you changed the question completely, but this still applies to all binding projects)

Answer (score 0):

in xamarin you wont be able to do things like you did in gradle but you can add a binding project to bind the java to .NET for you

now you could either go through workout explained in this link for [AAR](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-an-aar/) files (that requires you to download and compile your intended libraries manually)

or

check [this little extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a3257c7-473a-4790-9610-9a561eed0b8c) from visual studio gallery, it is really easy to work with.

i have tested it myself and it works nice.